# Django model to admin, integer fields and textfield are not visible in admin section

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

```
class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    father_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    age = models.SmallIntegerField
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    address = models.TextField
    email = models.EmailField(default="")
    id = models.AutoField
    std = models.SmallIntegerField
    remarks = models.TextField
```

I have created a model called Student and added it to Django admin and migrated it. There was no problem with migration. When I tried to add a new student via admin page, I am only getting following fields, How can I get integer fields like  age in UI?
[image]

Comment: It should be `age = models.SmallIntegerField()`. Note `()` signs. Just add it for all fields and run makemigrations/migrate.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to create fields in a django model (which are equivalent to columns in table) you need to call the function of that specific field.

Here you are only referring to the specific function and not actually calling them.

Thus the solution:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    father_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    age = models.SmallIntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    address = models.TextField()
    email = models.EmailField(default="")
    id = models.AutoField()
    std = models.SmallIntegerField()
    remarks = models.TextField()
```